# c# binary using Azure running on Ubuntu using Mono

Tags: c#, azure, ubuntu, mono

I'm having issues running a binary compiled in Visual Studio. It uses Azure Service Bus and management SDK. Its works on Windows Mono but not on Ubuntu.  The solution is compiled using .Net Framework 4.6. It runs properly on windows.

I download Mono-Runtime on Ubuntu and tried to run on console. This is the error i get.

```
Could not load signature of Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials:ProcessHttpRequestAsync due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:<unknown type> member:<none>

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials' from assembly ''.
  at TestProject.ServiceBusManager..ctor () [0x00022] in <361059fca0ba4fdb9746f81f381c6004>:0 
  at Example.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in <4839397d23d646a0b5d49866c41eba66>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials' from assembly ''.
  at TestProject.ServiceBusManager..ctor () [0x00022] in <361059fca0ba4fdb9746f81f381c6004>:0 
  at Example.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in <4839397d23d646a0b5d49866c41eba66>:0
```

Comment: Based on my knowledge .Net Framework 4.6 only works on Windows platform. .Net core could work on Linux.  I guess maybe this class does not support on linux platform.

Comment: @walter, i install mono-devel on ubuntu and it works. Previously, i install mono-runtime. And i do have dlls in the same folder as well.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.0.201 (tarball Fri Oct 13 21:56:25 UTC 2017)